# Visual Studio error on command "attrib -r" on a dataset file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, dataset

I have downloaded a solution with multiple projects from TFS and getting 2 errors on building it.

error 1:
The command "attrib -r c:\web\idpm45\benchmarkloader\benchmarkloader\dataset\benchmarkimportdataset.cs /s
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\xsd.exe" /d /l:CS /namespace:BenchmarkLoader c:\web\idpm45\benchmarkloader\benchmarkloader\dataset\BenchmarkImportDataset.xsd /out:"c:\web\idpm45\BenchmarkLoader\benchmarkloader\dataset"
" exited with code 1.

error 2:
There was an error processing 'c:\web\idpm45\benchmarkloader\benchmarkloader\dataset\BenchmarkImportDataset.xsd'

Has anyone faced this attrib command errors?